# I am getting about 1 FPS in Pygame when I run my script. What in my code is causing this?

Tags: python, pygame

My computer isn't ancient, so not having enough processing power can't be the cause. I think that means it must be being caused by something in my code that takes a long time to execute. I have pored over my code but I do not see what possibly could be causing this. I would very much appreciate if someone could point out the cause of this to me. My code is in 4 modules:

**dungeon_crawl.py**

```
import pygame, sys

import game_function as gf
from tilemap import Tilemap
from player import Player

def run_game():
    # Start the game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    screen_info = pygame.display.Info()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_info.current_w, screen_info.current_h))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Dungeon Crawl')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Create objects for classes.
    tilemap = Tilemap(screen)
    player = Player(screen)

    # Set the background color.
    bg_color = (255,255,255)

    # Game loop
    while True:
        gf.check_events(player)
        player.update()
        gf.update_screen(bg_color, screen, player)
        clock.tick(30)

run_game()_
```

**game_function.py**

```
import pygame, sys

from tilemap import Tilemap

def check_events(player):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    # Quit if the player closes out of the window.
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                # Move the player to the right.
                player.moving_right = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.moving_right = False

def update_screen(bg_color, screen, player):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Create objects for classes.
    tilemap = Tilemap(screen)

    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    tilemap.draw_self(screen, player.x, player.y)
    player.blitme()

    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()
```

**player.py**

```
import pygame

class Player():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        # Load the hero image and the screen and get their rects.
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load('hero.bmp'))
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        # Set position on screen.
        self.rect.centerx = 330
        self.rect.centery = 330

        # Set initial coordinates on the tilemap.
        self.x = 1000
        self.y = 1000

        # Movement flag
        self.moving_right = False

    def update(self):
        """Update the player's position based on the movement flags."""
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.centerx += 1

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the player."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

**tilemap.py**

```
import pygame
from pygame import sprite

class Tilemap():

    def __init__(self, screen):
        # Set constants.
        BLACK = (0,0,0)
        LIGHTGREY = (200,200,200)
        DARKGREY = (100,100,100)

        NONE = 0
        FLOOR = 1
        WALL = 2

        # Link each structure to its color.
        self.colors =   {
                            NONE: BLACK,
                            FLOOR: LIGHTGREY,
                            WALL: DARKGREY
                        }

        # Decide which structures block movements.
        self.block_movement =   {
                                    NONE: 'n',
                                    FLOOR: 'n',
                                    WALL: 'y',
                                }

        # Create tilemap.
        tiles = []

        for x in range(0, 2000):
            tiles.append([])
            for y in range(0, 2000):
                tiles[x].append(NONE)

        for i in range(0, 10):
            tiles[1001][1000 + i] = WALL

        self.tiles = tiles

        # Set size of tiles and map height/width in tiles.
        self.TILESIZE = 60
        self.MAPHEIGHT = 11
        self.MAPWIDTH = 11

    def draw_self(self, screen, playerx, playery):
        """Draw the map."""
        for row in range(self.MAPHEIGHT):
            for column in range(self.MAPWIDTH):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colors[self.tiles[playerx + column][playery + row]], (column * self.TILESIZE, row * self.TILESIZE, self.TILESIZE, self.TILESIZE))
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you update the screen, you create a new `Tilemap`. In the initializer you have the following code:

```
for x in range(0, 2000):
    tiles.append([])
    for y in range(0, 2000):
        tiles[x].append(NONE)
```

Meaning that you unnecessarily recreating the `Tilemap` using a nested for loop that iterates `2,000 * 2,000 = 4,000,000` times (each frame!), just to create a 2D-list. This list doesn't need to be created every frame; it just needs to be created before each scene in the game. I believe it's what's causing the performance issues.

My guess is that you want to pass the `tilemap` variable in **dungeon_crawl.py** into the function `gf.update_screen`, rather than recreating it at the beginning of the function.